# pegar valores das ID's dos inputs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tenho que fazer um sistema de leilão e estou planejando como fazer o countdown para vários produtos de uma vez só, cada um com seu número de segundos. Estou pensando em fazer com PHP e jQuery. O problema é que preciso pegar o restante das ID's dos elementos puxados do banco de dados pelo PHP. Por exemplo, vou fazer uma listagem (por exemplo) com php de 3 elementos, cada um com o nome:

- minhaid_43231234
- minhaid_99
- minhaid_3023321

Preciso pegar os números depois do **minhaid_** sendo que eu só sei que no `id` vai ter sempre `minhaid_`

Answer (score 0):

Se for só baseado no PHP você pode fazer um explode para separar o minhaid_

```
<?php
$v = "minhaid_43231234";
echo explode("minhaid_", $v)[1];
?>
```